# Mysql Count Distinct Rows in 2 of 3 Group By Columns

Tags: mysql, group-by

My table groups by 3 columns. In result of my query, I need the count of unique combinations of two of those group by columns. I can make this work using a sub query. But in a large dataset, this makes the query take a very long time to run. Is there way to do this without using a subquery?

Here is an example. Give the following table `group_test`.

```
+-------+--------+--------+
| A     | B      | C      |
+-------+--------+--------+
| apple | orange | banana |
| apple | orange | grape  |
| apple | pear   | banana |
| kiwi  | orange | banana |
+-------+--------+--------+
```

I want to create a query that returns the following results. There are 2 rows that have apple and orange in columns A and B. Like so:

```
+-------+--------+--------+----------+
| a     | b      | c      | count_ab |
+-------+--------+--------+----------+
| apple | orange | banana |        2 |
| apple | orange | grape  |        2 |
| apple | pear   | banana |        1 |
| kiwi  | orange | banana |        1 |
+-------+--------+--------+----------+
```

I can do this using a subquery, like so:

```
SELECT
a, b, c, 
(SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT c) FROM group_test g2 WHERE g2.a = g1.a AND g2.b = g1.b) AS count_ab
FROM
group_test g1
GROUP BY
a, b, c;
```

But like I said, this is not efficient over a large dataset (1 million+ rows). I thought I could do something like this:

```
SELECT
a, b, c, 
count(distinct a, b)
FROM
group_test g1
GROUP BY
a, b, c;
```

But that is not returning the results I want. It just returns 1 for each row.

Any ideas? Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You might get better performance by avoiding the correlated subquery in the SELECT list, and using a JOIN operation to an inline view instead,

```
SELECT t.a, t.b, t.c, s.cnt
  FROM group_test g1
  JOIN ( SELECT r.a, r.b, COUNT(*) AS cnt
           FROM group_test r
          GROUP BY r.a, r.b
       ) s
    ON s.a = t.a AND s.b = t.b
 GROUP
    BY t.a, t.b, t.c
```

For best performance, you'd want an index defined

```
... ON group_test (a, b, c)
```

Comment: This approached performed better than the subquery.

Answer (score 0):

This is your query:

```
SELECT a, b, c, 
       (SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT c)
        FROM group_test g2
        WHERE g2.a = g1.a AND g2.b = g1.b
       ) AS count_ab
FROM group_test g1
GROUP BY a, b, c;
```

In MySQL, your best hope for making this faster is indexing.  I would recommend:

```
create index idx_group_test_a_b_c on group_test(a, b, c);
```